# CircleCI with no tests

Tags: circleci

I want to use CircleCI just to push my docker image to Dockerhub when I merge with master. I am using CircleCI in other projects where it is more useful and want to be consistent (as well as I am planning to add tests later). However all my builds fail because CircleCI says: "NO TESTS!", which is true. How can I disable CircleCI from checking for tests presence.

Comment: Have you found another way ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I solved the problem by overriding the test section of circle.yml:

```
test:
  override:
    - echo "test"
```

This works for CircleCI 1.0

Comment: You can also use `true` as the command. This is theoretically better because it actually returns a status code instead of just outputting text.

Comment: Please be careful to choose CircleCI 1.0 otherwise this will not work.

Comment: How can I achieve the same with 2.0?

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, as cited on [this discussion](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/invalid-command-error/4414/2), you can use `"true"` to skip tests:

```
# circle.yml
...

test:
  override:
    - "true"

...
```

Please notice the double quotes as otherwise it won't work.

I hope that is helpful as it worked for me!

Comment: Double quotes! YAML strikes again... is YAML the AppleScript of data formats?

Answer (score 2):

CircleCI 2.0 no longer requires a test section in your config.yml. Just leave it off!